# Different between CONCAT and CONCATENATE in SQL

Tags: sql, syntax, concatenation

Is there a difference? If so, when is one used instead of the other?

Comment: You can look that up really easy in the docs of the DB system you are using?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.